# How to assign a variable to an absolute address in c?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, cortex-m

I am trying to access the PMC_PCER0 and enable it for PID14 on an ARM Cortex M3. I am asked to make a void function that reads a button and "returns" (as my professor insists to call it) its value. Anyway, here is the problem:

```
void readButton( unsigned int *button)
{
   do something yo;
}
```

I have an address for `PMC_PCER0` and let's suppose for the sake of the question it is at `0xfff123da` and this `PMC_PER0` has 32 PIOs, one of which is PID and happens to start at the 14th place, so I need to activate this one.

In order to activate it, do I need to mask `PMC_PCER0` using the `or operator?

I know I can define `PMC_PCER0` as follows

```
#define PMC_PCER0 (0xfff123da)
```

However, this will just  give `PMC_PCER0` the value of `0xfff123da`, but what I want to do is `PMC_PCER0` to actually have that address. And later I want to mask it. I'd appreciate it if you explained it in details.

Comment: Why not use the vendor's (CMSIS) headers for peripheral modules in your MCU? Every manufacturer of MCUs provides such headers.

Comment: @Olaf This is not a program for a PC but rather an embedded processor, the ARM Cortex M3. The hardware engineer has provided the addresses to use. The addresses the compiler/linker produced would not works.

Comment: @QuentinUK: I'm very sure CMSIS headers are not for a PC. And a PC does not have an MCU, but a CPU (although the differences are diminishing). There should be a header file anyway. The name is from a register of a peripheral module in an Atmel MCU (AT91SAM3*) and I'm very confident Atmel **does** provide headers. So what was your point?

Comment: so the point of asking the public questions is to feel bad about yourself, because people here are literally good at nothing but down-rating your questions. yet no one has given a satisfactory answer! of course i dont mean you guys who commented ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so how do you load or store something at some address in C?  You need an array or pointer right?  How do you assign a pointer an address?

```
unsigned int *p;
...
p = (unsigned int *)0x12345678;
```

And then *p = 10; will write a 10 to that address right?  or p[0] = 10;, elementary C language programming, has nothing to do with microcontrollers or operating systems.

The problem you end up with though is optimizers.  if *p or p[0] is not used later then there is no reason at all to generate code.  even if it does generate code there is no guarantee that it actually does the store or load

```
void myfun ( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int *p;
    p = (unsigned int *)0x12345678;
    *p = x;
}
```

How do you tell the compiler or how do you use the language to ask the compiler to actually do a memory operation?

```
volatile unsigned int *p;
p = (unsigned int *)0x12345678;
```

so try making your define look something like this

```
#define PMC_PCER0   (*((volatile unsigned int *)0xfff123da))
```

AND understand that that is still not a guarantee that the 1) compiler will do a bus operation 2) that the bus operation will be the size you desire.  if you want to guarantee such things then instead

```
#define PMC_PCER0 (0xfff123da)
```

and make a small asm file to link into the project, or put this in your bootstrap.

```
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
```

and then use it

```
void myfun ( unsigned int x )
{
    PUT32(PMC_PCER0,x);
}
```

This has a performance cost, but it has significant benefits as well, first off being the compiler if remotely compliant must perform the function calls in order and all of them.  so you are insured you get your load or store and you are insured it is of the right size.  Second all of your accesses to peripherals and other special addresses are controlled through an abstraction layer that when placed on a chip simulator or on top of a operating system, or when doing your own testing against a handmade test bench (emulator) you already have an abstraction layer at the C function level that is easy to port.  if you want to debug what is going on, you can use this abstraction layer to insert breakpoints or printfs or whatever.

Take it or leave it, it took me years to trip up the compiler into not generating the right instructions using the volatile trick.  If you dont learn at least a little assembly language, and dont regularly disassemble the tool produced code, you will struggle more than necessary when something goes wrong like the wrong instruction being generated by the compiler or items being loaded to the wrong places by the linker (chip doesnt boot, program hangs, etc).  THEN with that how to move the toolchain past the problem.

Yes I know your desired function is a load not a store, I assume you can figure it out from here.

This was all elementary C language programming stuff, possibly why nobody wanted to jump in and answer.  Also the libraries that come free for the microcontroller you are using and for all other families and brands uses these kinds of tricks although some of them are a bit scary so take them with a grain of salt (or use them as a reference and not necessarily directly as you may end up owning their issues and maintenance).